# convert scala map string -> string to string -> map

Tags: scala

I am trying to convert the following scala code?

```
val orig = Map("command.stamp" -> 5, "command.another" -> "0", "level1.level2.level3" -> 10) which would translate to
```

to a map.  new map needs to support multiple value types and more then two levels

```
val newMap = Map("command" -> Map("stamp" -> 5, "another" -> "0"), "level1" -> Map("level2" -> Map("level3" -> 10)))
```

Additionally I have to convert it to json.  Been using Json.toJson(newMap) but it has probably with multiple types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the assumption that you always have the key pattern "one.two" this will work:

```
val orig = Map("command.stamp" -> 5, "command.another" -> 0)

newMap = orig.foldLeft(immutable.Map[String, Map[String, Int]]())((prev, elem) => {
  val ar = elem._1.split('.')
  prev.get(ar(0)) match {
    case None => (prev + (ar(0) -> immutable.Map((ar(1), elem._2))))
    case Some(entry) =>
      prev + (ar(0) -> (immutable.Map((ar(1), elem._2)) ++ entry))
  }
})
```

basically Iam folding and propagating the output map. The first case just checks, if there isn't already an entry for this key. Otherwise if there is, the value map will be extracted and explicitly appended.
It don't know if that is the best solution. I thought about version with zip and other iterative approaches but there weren't.

Comment: That works but my use case is a little different then I thought

Comment: @Mikel did the same but in a better manner. Tell me how your use-case differs or edit the question accordingly. Maybe this will help.

Comment: Isn't a tree like structure more reasonable?

Comment: before turning it into a Json?   what would you use to turn it into a json?

Comment: Are you using your initial Map to turn your stuff to json and therefore you want to use the "in-between" Map?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120258/discussion-between-sascha10000-and-richs).

Answer (score 3):

```
scala> map.groupBy(_._1.split('.')(0))
          .mapValues(_ map { case(k, v) => (k.split('.')(1), v) })
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]] = 
          Map(command -> Map(stamp -> 5, another -> 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this

```
map.foldLeft(Map[String,Map[String,Int]]()) {
    case (map, (k,v)) =>
      val keys = k.split('.')
      map + ((keys(0), map.getOrElse(keys(0), Map[String,Int]()) + (keys(1) -> v)))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume a `testMap` adding another prefix group for demo purposes:

```
  val testmap:Map[String,Int] = Map("command.stamp" -> 5, "command.another" -> 0, 
                                    "command2.stamp2" -> 4, "command2.another2" -> 1)
```

We can first tokenize by "." and group by the prefix and secondarily parse each submap to strip the prefix:

```
 for {
    (k,v) <- testmap.groupBy{ _._1.split("\\.")(0) }  //first tokenize by "." and group by prefix
  } yield (k -> v.map{case(subKey,subValue) => subKey.replace(k,"").replace("\\.","") -> subValue })  //stripping prefix from submaps
```